# NSInvalidArgumentException iphone

Tags: nsstring

```
NSString *str = self.completedDrills.drillId;
```

I am simply setting string but it is giving me exception

NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFDictionary drillTitle]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Here is my Drill class

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "Category.h"
#import "Users.h"
#import "Benchmark.h"

@interface Drill : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *drillId;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *drillTitle;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *crewName;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *objectives;
@property (nonatomic, retain) Category *category;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *benchmarks;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *crewMembers;
@property (nonatomic, retain) Users *currentUser;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *totalDrillTime;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *timestamp;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *error;

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder;
- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)encoder;

@end
```

Answer (score 1):

self.completedDrills incorrectly initialized. Do this:

```
self.completedDrills = [Drill new];
```

And add Init method to Drill.m:

```
- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {

    }
    return self;
}
```